# How to set Maximum Plain text size (kb) of a message received via Send Email

Tags: .net

I,m not able to send email more than 60kb plain text,so any one please help me how to set the max size.

```
private void Send(MailMessage mail)
   {
        using (SmtpClient smtpServer = GetSmtpClientSetting())
            {                
                smtpServer.Send(mail);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I think we would need more information. 
What is the error message? How is the email object created? Could you please show the code for `GetSmtpClientSetting()`.

Comment: private void Send(MailMessage mail)
        {
          using (SmtpClient smtpServer = GetSmtpClientSetting())
            {   
            smtpServer.Send(mail);
            }
        }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ServiceLocator.Instance.Resolve<ILogger>().LogException(ex);
                throw ex;
            }
        }

Comment: This is my code bu i'm not sure this problem is occurring here and may be from here  " Publisher.Publish(emailCommand.ToBackground()); " .i,m using this with background process.

Comment: That code does not seem complete. I is just a catch block after the code you showed above.

Comment: First of all, what is the exception message? What do you see in the logs? (as I can see it is logged out)

Answer (score 0):

Neither `SmtpClient` Nor `MailMessage` doesn't define the mail size. This is most probably configured at the SMTP Configuration . You Might need to check your SMTP server configuration for size limits.